# i am unable to install oracle jdk 1.8 on my centos 7 using wget

Tags: java-8, wget, centos7

following is wget command

wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz"

after entering above command on centos 7 terminal follwing is the output

unable to resolve host address  'edeilvery.oracle.com'

Answer (score 1):

Check you migh have a proxy if you do, excute this :

```
   export http_proxy://address:port/
   export https_proxy://address:port/
```

if not try also this :

```
   dhclient -v
```

Comment: yes brother i did export of proxy using command mentioned by you already

Comment: try this : `wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u4 5-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Comment: same problem: unable to resolve host address 'edelivery.oracle.com'

Comment: there is no person in the world who can solve above problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170957/how-do-i-bypass-the-license-page-to-download-oracle-sun-java-on-a-server-with-wg

Comment: can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: i guess there must be problem with my  /etc/resolv.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this command

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

This is not the version you're looking for but this will definitely solve your issue of JDK :)
This will perfrom few redirection before downloading the actual file.

**Note: Command tested on CentOS 6.5 on 09/11/2017**